# Route stopped working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

One of my routes is returning this error message:

```
Not Found 

The requested resource /jackpots was not found on this server.
```

When I change the route name to anything else e.g. route-1, it works.

Server is running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/jackpots via artisan serve

How can I resolve this?

Edit 1:

**Does not work:**

Route::get('jackpots', 'JackpotsController@getIndex');

**Works:**

Route::get('jackpot', 'JackpotsController@getIndex');

Comment: Show us your `routes/web.php`.

Comment: Please show the code for the `Route` that's causing the error.

Comment: @RossWilson added the code. It's that simple really. Even a simple change to the name of the route makes the difference.

Comment: @RossWilson I figured out the issue; please see answer I've submitted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the problem had nothing to do with anything in the routes/web.php script.

In my public directory, I also had a folder with the same name as a URL endpoint i.e.

Folder structure

```
public
|__jackpots
```

web/routes.php

```
Route::get('jackpots', 'JackpotsController@getIndex');
```

This somehow confuses the php server (as well as apache) into thinking you're trying to access the public/jackpots folder whose permissions won't allow you to do that.

I renamed the public/jackpots folder and the problem was resolved.

Comment: This is because the webserver is usually set up to look for files or directories first and then send the request through the app if they don't exist e.g. look at the `public/.htaccess` for the block `# Handle Front Controller...`. This is so things like assets (css, js, images, etc) will still work in the normal/default way.

Comment: Very cool. Thanks for the tip on `.htaccess`. Always nice to have a more concise comprehension of the architecture.